# Can not extract data from a form to show it in another page, REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I am trying to get data from a form using react hook form in REACT, but I am also using an API to fill some inputs automatically based on a code of location. The inputs that are filled with this API are not being registred by the form, only the ones that you fill manually. Can someone help me? It's not showing any error

```
const [ cepInfo, setCepInfo ] = useState(
    {  
        Street: ''
    }
)

const { Street } = cepInfo

const cep = watch('CEP')

const isCepValid = /^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{3}$/.test(cep)

useEffect(() => {

    const getCepInfo = async () => {

        if (isCepValid) {
            const resp = await db.get(`/${cep}/json`);    <-- API filling the inputs

            const newCepInfo = { 
                Street: resp.data.street
            }

        setCepInfo(newCepInfo);

        } else {
            setCepInfo(
                {         
                    Street: ''
                }
            )
        }
    }

    getCepInfo()

}, [watch('CEP')])

const handleSubmitForm = (data) => {

    addOrderInfos(data)

    navigate('/success')
}

watch()

<form
    onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSubmitForm)}
    id="orderForm">

    <input            <-- the input that automatically fills other inputs
        type="text"
        id="CEP" 
        placeholder="CEP"
        {...register('CEP')}
    />

    <input            <-- the input that is filled automatically and is not being registred 
        type="text"
        id="Street"
        placeholder='Street'
        value={Street}
        {...register('Street')}    
    />
<form>
```

```
const [ orderInfos, setOrderInfos ] = useState({
    CEP: '',
    Street: ''
})

function addOrderInfos(data) {

    setOrderInfos(data)
}
```

I tried to **console.log(watch())** to see the values of the inputs and it's not updating the data after you get the infos with the API. I really don't know what to do next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need the state, we can just register that field and update it with `setValue(fieldName: string, newValue:unknown)` from react-hook-form. In your case, it might be like this: `setValue('Street', 'newValue')`

not sure if this is what you want to achieve but I made it here as an example
https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-playground-gn78fg?file=/src/index.js